# How do i collect bug reports from published android app from google play console

Tags: android, google-play, crash-reports

I want to collect bug reports from users of my android app. My app is available on google play. There is a way to see app crashes in google play console in Quality > Android vitals > Crashes & ANRs.I want to know there is a special configuration from apk to get those crash reports from above path in google play console.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it just works, tracks all your exceptions and ANRs. In fact you probably can't opt-out.

If you want some customization then use [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics) or some custom lib, like [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)